# Python ctypes dll call access violation when using library functions

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes, access-violation

I have a c file containing two functions. This file is compiled with gcc to a dll, then calles from python with ctypes. The simple function `try1()` works fine, but when calling `try2()`, it throws a

```
windows error: access violation when writing 0x0
```

My guess: there is some problem with the c library functions that are called from the included libraries: printf, strcpy, etc. But malloc and strlen works fine...

How can i fix this? What am i doing wrong? Thanks!
Here are the code extracts:

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int try1(int x)
{
    return x+2;
}
int try2(int x)
{
    char* str;
    str = malloc(strlen("text")+1);   // works
    strcpy(str, "text");              // problematic line
    printf("x: %i\n", x);             // problematic line
    free(str);                        // works
    return x+2;
}
```

compilation:

```
gcc -shared -o mylib.dll mylib.c -O3 -Wall
```

python call:

```
import ctypes
mylib = ctypes.cdll.mylib
print mylib.try1(5)    # works fine, prints 7
print mylib.try2(5)    #crashes with the access violation error, if the problematic lines are present.
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, corrected. But that is just a mistyping here, not the problem.

Comment: Your unmodified code works for me with mingw-gcc 4.7.2 under Windows 7 64 Bit and Python 2.7.6 as well as Python 3.3.0

Comment: When you say that malloc works, have you tested the return value?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that the problem was this:
I built the dll within cygwin, with the cygwin's built-in gcc. It linked the cygwin1.dll runtime, and the python's ctypes somehow did not tolerate this.
When I built the dll with MinGW's gcc, it all works now, as it uses windows runtime.